# Git always asks for my ssh-key passphrase

Tags: git, github

I have a problem that occurs when using `git`.

When I use the command `git pull origin my_branch` or `git fetch` or `git push origin my_branch`, git always asks for my passphrase for key. I don't understand why this occurs?

Can someone please explain why and how to avoid entering the passphrase each time.

```
$ git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/home/khanhpn/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: read about this https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: Please mark one answer as accepted if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Like Nasreddine says, it's because your key is encrypted with a passphrase to prevent others from reading it.

The most convenient way of using passphrased keys is by using [`ssh-agent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) to start an authentication agent (which runs in the background):

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
Agent pid 44304
```

...and then using [`ssh-add`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) to register your key with the agent so that it's used automatically for subsequent SSH connections:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/khanhpn/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

You'll be asked to enter your passphrase when you run `ssh-add`, but you won't need to do so again while `ssh-agent` is running.

You can find more information [on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/).  Also note that you'll have to do this every time you log in, so you might like to add the `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` step to your `.profile` script.

Comment: is that a file `.profile`  that we need to put that command in that file  ?

Answer (score 14):

It's because your private SSH key is protected using a passphrase. You can remove it using this command (**not recommended since anyone could copy your key and use it to access your repos/account**):

```
$ ssh-keygen -p
Enter file in which the key is (/path/to/your/.ssh/key):
```

enter your current passphrase when prompted here:

```
Enter old passphrase:
Key has comment 'rsa w/o comment'
```

leave empty if you want to remove the passphrase when prompted here:

```
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Comment: This works well, but you have to understand that anybody having access to your private key file will be able to access your remote account without any password (e.g. what happens if your laptop is stolen?). A much safer option is to use ssh-agent, as suggested by Will Vousden.

Comment: maybe I should emphasize that part